# subscribe to Observable with Interval callback never fire

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I am trying to subscribe for an Observable with Interval

```
 return IntervalObservable.create(10000)
     .startWith(0) // needs a value, but won't be used
     .flatMap(() => this._http.get(eazyUrl)).map(res => res.text())
```

this is the subscribe code

```
var answer = this.LogService.getAdminHiererchy()
        var Fdata: any;
        answer.subscribe((response) => {

            Fdata = response;
            localStorage.setItem("AdminHiererchy", response);
            console.log(Fdata);

        },
            error => {
                var err = error;

                alert("error");
            }

        , () =>{this.readyFunc(Fdata);})
```

this.readyFunc is never fire.

if I remove the intreval the code working just fine

```
   return  this._http.get(eazyUrl)
        .map(res => res.text());
```

also tried finally with no luck

```
 answer.finally(() => this.readyFunc(Fdata)).subscribe((response) => {...
```

also tried with timer with same resualt

```
 return Observable.timer(0, 10000)
  .flatMapTo(this._http.get(eazyUrl)).map(res => res.text());;
```

Why does the callback not fire when useing intreval

Comment: Why do you think the callback should be called?

Comment: to handle the data when it ready

Comment: The callback is the third argument passed to subscribe. The first one  called when an event is emitted. The second one is called when an error happens. When is the third one called?

Comment: @JBNizet what do you mean? what is your point? the third argument should run when the data is ready and can be use for the doom.what am I missing here?

Comment: No. The third callback is called when the observable **completes**. I.e. where there is no event to emit anymore. That never happens, since your observable never completes: it sends a new even every x milliseconds.

Comment: @JBNizet ok so what is the right option to listen to the api and make updates when data changes?

Comment: It's unclear what you want to achieve, why you're using interval, etc.. But you probably just want to do your job in the first callback, not the third one.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `startWith(0)`, I suspect it terminates your stream before you subscribe.

Other options (since IntervalObservable is not documented and hard to invoke in jsbin):

1. Use instead `Observable.timer(1000).flatMap(...)`
2. Use `Observable.of(0).delay(1000).flatMap(...)`
3. Add `.do(v => console.log(v))` after each line of your first method:

   `return IntervalObservable.create(10000)
     .do(v => console.log('stage 1: ', v)
     .startWith(0) // needs a value, but won't be used
     .do(v => console.log('stage 2: ', v)
     .flatMap(() => this._http.get(eazyUrl)).map(res => res.text())
     .do(v => console.log('stage 3: ', v)`